# onClick show iframe 5000 and then hide

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to build an impression test for a remote usability test using HTML, CSS and jQuery. The user needs to click on a button to start the impression test, which will show the page of the client in an iframe for 5 seconds and then hide itself.

I looked for many codes very similar to this but not exactly what I needed and I can't make it work myself as my jQuery knowledge is yet v poor.

So, what I'm looking for is something like this:

on click show iframe 5000

hide

I tried using this bit of code to show on click with the css iframe {display:none};

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $("#show").click(function() {
            $("#iframe1").show("5000");
        });
    });
</script>
```

Thinking "it will show after the click for 5 seconds and then go back to normal display: none.

But no... It shows on click and it stays there.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: The parameter of [`.show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/) only tells the duration of the opening animation. (or is an object with properties, including duration).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how you would do it in jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#show").click(function() {
        $("#iframe1").show().delay(5000).hide(500);
    });
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5vC68/

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use the [window.setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout) event. For example:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  $('#element').hide();

  window.setTimeout(function() { 
    $('#element').show(); 
  }, 5000);

});
```

You can swap the hide/show around to suit your needs.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NfCHG/1/

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function() {
  $( "#show" ).click(function() {
  $( "#iframe1" ).show().delay(500);
  $( "#iframe1" ).show().delay(5000);
});
});
</script>
```